# How to use "--path" in git config?

Tags: git, path, config, relative-path

It looks like Git can't resolve the `~/` path for `submodule`.

I tried to put `~/foo/myproject.git` in *.gitmodules* as the submodule URL path, but when I try

```
$ git submodule init
```

I get an error saying Git can't find the repository.

If I change it to a path like `/home/userA/foo/myproject.git`, everything works fine.

I checked the help from Git. It looks like the `--path` can do something.

I don't like using an absolute path because sometimes the full path is not under my control. Is there a way to use a resolved path?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$HOME/foo/myproject.git`, it works is better than `~`. Tilde is just a shortcut, its expansion isn't always good.

Git submodule paths can be relative since a long time ago, so it's always better to tell gitconfig the relative path.

Comment: Thanks. I would try it later. I hope GIT can add the path of submodule as what I put in instead of converting it into absolute path.

Comment: Note: `$HOME` does not work in `.gitconfig` for OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Strange. Why do you need absolute path in gitconfig?

Comment: That is a good point. Thinking about it for half a second, it turns out I didn't.